ATmega64 AVR Assembly Program: Issue with Memory Access and Displaying Input on Seven-Segment Display
Write and debug a program that enters numbers typed on the keyboard
ry into a buffer, converts it into a seven-segment code and places it in video memory. Again
the entered digit falls into the low position of a 4-digit decimal number,
the remaining digits are shifted to the left, the most significant digit is lost. Current status
Video memory loss is constantly indicated in the 7SEG-MPX4-CC block. Keys ∗
and ] are not yet used.

.equ segment_port = portd ; порт d для управления семисегментным дисплеем
.equ keypad_port = portb ; порт a для управления клавиатурой
.equ keypad_ddr = ddrb     ; регистр направления для клавиатуры
.equ keypad_pin = pinb   ; регистр для чтения состояния клавиатуры

.equ scan_delay = 2 ; задержка между сканированием

.equ rows = 3
.equ cols = 3

.equ loop_delay = 5 ; задержка между итерациями основного цикла

.org 0x0000
    rjmp reset
init_external_memory_interface:
    ; Настройка EMI
    ldi r16, (1 << SRE) | (1 << SRW10) | (1 << SRW11)  ; Разрешить доступ к внешней памяти и разрешить запись
    out MCUCR, r16

    ; Другие настройки по необходимости

    ret    

reset:
; Инициализация интерфейса внешней памяти
    call init_external_memory_interface
    ldi r16, 0    ; инициализация буфера с нулевыми значениями
    sts buffer, r16
    sts buffer+1, r16
    sts buffer+2, r16
    sts buffer+3, r16
    
    ldi r16, 0    ; инициализация индекса
    sts index, r16
       ldi r16, 0    ; инициализация индекса
       
    ; настройка портов для клавиатуры и семисегментного дисплея
    ldi r16, 0xff ; все биты на вывод для семисегментного дисплея (port d)
    out ddrd, r16

    ldi r16, 0xff ; все биты на вывод для цифр (port e)
    out ddre, r16
    ldi r16, 0b00000001
    out pine, r16
    ldi r16, 0b00000111
    out pind,r16
    ldi r16, 0b0000000 ; подтяжка к питанию для строк клавиатуры
    out keypad_ddr, r16

main_loop:
    ; считывание нажатой кнопки с клавиатуры
    ldi r16, (1 << rows) - 1 ; подача 1 на каждую строку
    out keypad_port, r16
    ldi r16, 0 ; начальное значение столбца

scan_loop:
    ; считывание состояния столбцов
    in r17, keypad_pin
    andi r17, 0x0f

    ; проверка наличия нажатой кнопки в текущем столбце и текущей строке
    tst r17
    brne button_pressed ; если есть нажатие в столбце, переходим к обработке нажатия
    rjmp next_column ; иначе переходим к следующему столбцу

next_column:
    ; переход к следующему столбцу
    ldi r18, 1
    lsl r18
    out keypad_port, r18 ; переключение на следующий столбец
    inc r16 ; увеличение счетчика столбцов
    cpi r16, cols
    brne scan_loop ; повторяем сканирование, пока не просканируем все столбцы
    rjmp main_loop ; если просканированы все столбцы, переходим к основному циклу

scan_delay_loop:
    dec r20
    brne scan_delay_loop

    rjmp main_loop ; повторить основной цикл

button_pressed:
    ; определение нажатой кнопки
    mov r18, r16 ; сохранение номера столбца
    add r18, r16 ; вычисление номера кнопки
    subi r18, 1 ; коррекция номера кнопки

    ; обновление буфера
    lds r19, index
    ldi r20, 4 ; размер буфера
    add r19, r20 ; смещение до конца буфера
    dec r19 ; адрес последней ячейки буфера

buffer_full:
    ldi r20, 0 ; сброс индекса на 0
buffer_not_full:
    st z+, r18 ; сохранение новой цифры в буфер
    sts index, r20 ; обновление индекса
    rjmp display_digits ; отображение содержимого буфера на семисегментном дисплее

display_digits:
    ; отображение содержимого буфера на семисегментном дисплее
    ldi r20, 0 ; инициализация счетчика цифр
    lds r19, index ; загрузка индекса буфера
    ldi r18, 4 ; размер буфера

display_loop:
    mov r16, r20 ; копирование счетчика цифр в регистр
    add r16, r16 ; удвоение счетчика
    lsl r16 ; умножение на 2 для индексации буфера
    add r19, r16 ; смещение адреса буфера
    lds r16, buffer ; загрузка текущей цифры из буфера
    mov r17, r20 ; копирование счетчика цифр в регистр
    add r17, r17 ; удвоение счетчика
    ldi r21, low(segment_code)  ; загрузить младший байт адреса segment_code
    ldi r22, high(segment_code) ; загрузить старший байт адреса segment_code
    add r21, r17 ; смещение адреса к сегментному коду
    ld r17, Z ; загрузка семисегментного кода
    out segment_port, r17 ; отображение цифры на дисплее
    inc r20 ; увеличение счетчика цифр
    cpi r20, 4 ; проверка, если отобразили все цифры
    brne display_loop

    ldi r20, loop_delay
delay_loop:
    dec r20
    brne delay_loop

    rjmp main_loop ; повторить основной цикл

.dseg
buffer:  .byte 4 ; буфер для хранения введенных цифр
index:  .byte 1 ; индекс текущего элемента в буфере

segment_code:
    .db 0b00111111, 0b00000110, 0b01011011, 0b01001111 ; семисегментный код для цифр 0-3
    .db 0b01100110, 0b01101101, 0b01111101, 0b00000111 ; семисегментный код для цифр 4-7
    .db 0b01111111, 0b01101111 ; семисегментный код для цифр 8-9

I expect the program to work, I tried it, I think there is an error in memory accesses, but I don’t understand how to fix it
